# Image uploaded incorrectly to s3 using amplify Storage (React Native - Expo - Amplify)

Tags: image, react-native, amazon-s3, expo, aws-amplify

- I'm trying to upload an image to s3 with Amplify Storage API.
- I use the EXPO imagePicker to upload the image from the phone to React-Native, and it's displayed correctly.
- Then I upload it to s3 with amplify Storage.put, and it reaches the correct folder in s3, with the proper filename that I gave it and with public access I provided (to the image and the bucket itself).
- BUT if I try to open the photo uri in s3 it doesn't display. When I inspect the browser it shows this error on console:

[image]

- If I paste in the browser the uri I get from Storage.get , i get this error:

[image]

- My code is the following (I helped myself with this tutorial https://blog.expo.io/how-to-build-cloud-powered-mobile-apps-with-expo-aws-amplify-2fddc898f9a2):

```
  _handleImagePicked = async (pickerResult) => {
    const s3path = 'fotos_cdcc/' + '186620' + '/'
    const imageName = '186620_4' + '.jpeg'
    const key = s3path + imageName
    const fileType = pickerResult.type;
    const access = { level: "public", contentType: 'image/jpg' };
    const imageData = await global.fetch(pickerResult.uri)
    const blobData = await imageData.blob()

    try {
      await Storage.put(
        key, 
        blobData, 
        access,
        fileType
        ).then(result => console.log(result))
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error: ', err)
    }
  }
```

- The pickerResult has this form:

```
Object {
"cancelled": false,
"height": 750,
"type": "image",
"uri": "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/021D6288-9E88-4080-8FBF-49F5195C2073/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fcaballos-app-dd2fa92e-4625-47e7-940e-1630e824347a/ImagePicker/D9EE1F24-D840-457F-B884-D208FFA56892.jpg",
"width": 748,
}
```

- I tried making the bucket and the photo public in s3, but the error persists.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you see the file in amazon s3 console?

Comment: @Cherniv yes I do. And even more, i have images uploaded to the same s3 folder directly from my computer (the ones that are displayed correctly) and there seems to be no difference between them and the conflictive one uploaded by Storage.put

Comment: When I saw the error, it may be an awsserver access issue. Check the socket or access rights.

Comment: @hongdevelop I made everything public (bucket, image) and the iam user has full permission, so I don't think the access rights are the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is not an issue with aws-amplify, instead with `fetch` and `blob`. Can you try this?

```
function urlToBlob(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onerror = reject;
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
              resolve(xhr.response);
          }
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.responseType = 'blob'; // convert type
      xhr.send();
  })
}
```

Then instead of

```
const imageData = await global.fetch(pickerResult.uri)
const blobData = await imageData.blob()
```

Try

```
const blobData = await urlToBlob(pickerResult.uri)
```

Please find full discussion https://github.com/expo/firebase-storage-upload-example/issues/13

Comment: We made it work with another solution but still had problems uploading in some phones. Just changed it to your solution and worked! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the tips !

Comment: Hi! Sorry for replying 4 years later but is there a solution in Dart and Flutter because I have the same problem and can't find help anywhere